# Using HighStocks with highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm using the Angular directive for HighCharts, https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng.

However I want to use the HighStock option which should be possible according to the above link by setting useHighStocks: true.

When I try this the chart won't load at all, but works just fine when it's set to false. I even tried to include the highstock.js from official site but with no luck.

Original jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/7cAq3/

My non-working highstock jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/achronos/7LZv4/1/

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7, 1, 1, 19, 15, 10]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },
    xAxis: {currentMin: 0, currentMax: 10, minRange: 1},
    loading: false,
    useHighStocks: true
}
```

What can I do to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it on my own, apparenty you can't include both highcharts.js and highstock.js at the same time. When including highstock.js, the highcharts.js functionality is included, however it does not work vice versa.

So, the trick is to only include highstock.js!

Comment: @Oskar Eriksson Thanks This is really useful and saved a lot of time for me

Comment: @Oskar Eriksson from changing  highcharts to highstock the only change is to add chartConfig.useHighStocks = true; ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use highcharts-ng and highstocks by including `highstock-all.js`.  I believe this is also the standalone version of highstocks too (please correct me if I'm wrong) so happy days.  The cost is 274Kb minified if you can live with that.